# ¿Cómo puedo quitar hash # de URL redireccionada de una página externa?

Tags: php, javascript

Cuando hago una llamada de anclaje en medio de una página diferente a la que estoy navegando, la url del navegador elimina el hash # del ancla, pero vuelve al valor inicial.

El gran problema es que cuando finalmente me deshago del hash, el hipervínculo de anclaje deja de funcionar.

He intentado diferentes opciones para resolver este problema, pero por el momento ninguna ha funcionado.

```
   <a href="index.php#has1" onclick="changeURL()">Seccion1</a>

function changeURL() {
  window.history.replaceState( {} , 'index.php#has1', 'index.php' );
  alert("the url changes, but when I close alert, url returns to its origin");
}
```

Otras opciones sin éxito:

```
//window.history.pushState(null, "", "index.php");
//window.location.hash='';

<script>
    $('index.php#promo').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        //the rest of the function is the same.
    });
</script>
```

Resultado esperado: "www.mysite.com/index.php" (En la parte del código donde tengo el id de llamada, más o menos a mitad de la página web)

Resultado actual: "www.mysite.com/index.php.#has1"

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316415/jquery-scroll-prevent-anchor-text-from-appearing-in-url

Comment: Has probado con el parámetro preventDefault()?

Comment: @Kiko, gracias por tu aporte.
El código funciona cuando estamos haciendo referencia en un mismo archivo .php o .html. El problema viene cuando haces estás en pag1.php y quieres ir a index.#has1.php
Son dos archivos diferentes

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @Emerita, si evectivamente he probado ese parámetro sin éxito. El problema es que o funciona el ancla o funciona el ocultar el hash, ambos no consigo que funcionen juntos.